# State of the Union?

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Good evening all!

Further advenntures in wordplay. Same rules as ever - the three overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions. Place one tile in each region, so that the tiles in any ellipse can be re-arranged to form an eight-letter solution to the corresponding clue!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The resolved Venn diagram is as follows:

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

This one has some tricky wordplay to resolve to work out what belongs where...

> The bottom-most ellipse is perhaps easiest to resolve: **MASSACRE** - since this alludes to the historical event, the [Boston Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Massacre), in which many died.
>  <sub>(At least, that's the connection I made - @caPNCApn in [their answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/121620/60644) points out that a 'BOSTON AREA' could also be a 'MASS. ACRE', since the city of Boston is in the state of Massachusetts (commonly abbreviated to Mass.) and an acre is a unit of area...)</sub>
>
>  The top-right ellipse clues **STRESSED**, because 'EIP' and 'TRAT' are DESSERTS (i.e. PIE and TART) spelled backwards!
>
>  Finally, the top-left ellipse clues **REMAINED**, a synonym of 'stayed', further clued here by inserting the US state MAINE into the word RED, since being '[in the red](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-red#:%7E:text=If%20a%20person%20or%20company,owe%20money%20to%20the%20bank.)' means being in debt.

Comment: Well done - I tossed a coin to decide who to tick!

Answer (score 5):

The tiles go into the ellipses like this:

> [image]

*STATE DEBT STAYED*

> MAINE is a state. REMAINED means STAYED. (not sure about DEBT).

*EIP TRAT*

> EIP TRAT is PIE and TART backwards. Both are DESSERTS. DESSERTS backwards is STRESSED.

*BOSTON AREA MURDER*

> BOSTON is in MASS. ACRE is an AREA. MASSACRE is MURDER.

Comment: Ha, up for over an hour with no bites and then two answers within less than a minute of each other! :) (I've just realised too that your 'BOSTON AREA MURDER' explanation contains further wordplay I hadn't spotted past the historical event, so +1)

Comment: @Stiv haha yup. I had a feeling you were working on it too.

Comment: @Stiv You have some stuff I don't so if you wanna add that wordplay to your answer it can be the complete one.

Comment: Okay, sure - will add credit...